# Accept international stripe payments in flask from India

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I have tried stripe but the problem is that in the docs they have listed that for accepting international payments from India, I have to be registered and also I need to add billing address, name of the customer and the payment intent. They have provided documentation on how to add names and payment intent, but I don't know how to implement the provided code in my application.

So, pls tell me how to do it...

Just in case you, this is my checkout code

```
@app.route('/create-checkout-session', methods=['POST'])
def create_checkout_session():
   session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price_data': {
               'currency': 'usd',
               'product_data': {
                   'name': 'T-shirt',
                },
                'unit_amount': 2000,
            },
            'quantity': 1,
       }],
       mode='payment',
       success_url=redirect("success.html"),
       cancel_url=redirect("cancel.html"),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Stripe Checkout you don't need to change your code; Checkout will collect the required information from your customer (name and billing address) on the Checkout page.

Comment: But what about the payment intent, customer name and shipping address?

Comment: Checkout will create the Payment Intent for you and include the customer name and billing address.  If you also need the shipping address you should [specify `shipping_address_collection` when creating the Checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection).

Answer (score 0):

**Edited respons**

This is how you can add other optional params:

```py
@bp.route('/create-checkout-session')
def create_checkout_session():
    domain_url = 'http://localhost:5000/'
    stripe.api_key = current_app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
    try:
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            success_url=domain_url + 'success',
            cancel_url=domain_url + 'cancelled',
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            billing_address_collection='required',
            mode='payment',
            customer='customer_id',
            line_items=[
                {
                  # using the price api takes care of the product well
                  # rather than having to specify name, currency etc
                  'quantity': 1,
                  'price': 'price_1IYgbtFWpU2KHaPLODAVgoKU'
                }
            ],
            payment_intent_data=[
                {
                  # Place your data here
                  'param-key': 'value',
                  # ...
                }
            ]
        )
        # your return statement
    except Exception as e:
        # your return statement
```

You can do this for the other params

Comment: I know that process, I am just asking how to add the shipping address that they are saying to add and add the customer name along with the intent.

Comment: Share a link to your code so I can look at it

Comment: And there isn't anything wrong with the code I just wanted to know do we need to add the intent of the transaction and customer name. If yes, then how?

Comment: You can add additional params as seen in the edited response